# Индексация и размерность массива

Tags: java

Добрый день) 
Есть метод, который получает на вход вектор 100х1 и матрицу 100х100 и 
рассчитывает расстояние между ними. Также 2 переменные p1 и p2 (w = 100).
Переменные введены для того, чтобы указывать размерность массивов.
Для первого случая нам необходимо найти расстояние  матрицы 80х100, поэтому
переменные p1 = 0, p2 = 79. Для второго найти расстояние 20х100, p1 = 80, p2 = 99.
Проблема в том, что когда я ищу расстояние для массива 20х100 и дохожу до этой строки

```
distance[i] = Math.round(Math.sqrt(rezult));
```

то тут я хочу обратится к 80 елементу, хотя мой массив состоит только с 20)
Не могу сообразить как переписать  индексацию массива, чтобы выводить еллементы по 20? 
Думала как-то вроде так:

```
distance[p2 - p1 - i] = Math.round(Math.sqrt(rezult));
```

но не работает), не хочется костыли писать)

Код метода:

```
double[] distance(int[] etalonVector, int[][] convertToMatrix, int p1, int p2){
int[] etalon = etalonVector;
        int [][] matrix = convertToMatrix;

        double [] distance = new double[p2 - p1 + 1];
        for (int i = p1; i < p2; i++){
            double rezult = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++){
                 rezult+= Math.pow(etalon[i] - matrix[i][j], 2);

                  }
            try {
                distance[p2 - p1 - i] = Math.round(Math.sqrt(rezult));
            } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println("exception when " + i);
            }
            }
        return distance;
    }

Вывод:

exception when 80
exception when 81
exception when 82
exception when 83
exception when 84
exception when 85
exception when 86
exception when 87
exception when 88
exception when 89
exception when 90
exception when 91
exception when 92
exception when 93
exception when 94
exception when 95
exception when 96
exception when 97
exception when 98
exception when 80
exception when 81
exception when 82
exception when 83
exception when 84
exception when 85
exception when 86
exception when 87
exception when 88
exception when 89
exception when 90
exception when 91
exception when 92
exception when 93
exception when 94
exception when 95
exception when 96
exception when 97
exception when 98
```

Comment: Объясните более подробно логику выбора параметров p1 и p2, особенно для второго случая.

Comment: @I.Perevoz первоначально мы загружаем картику и переводим ее в матрицу 100х100, потом с ней делаем различные манипуляции. Для первого случая p1 = 0, p2 = 79. У нас получается матрица 80х100, по которой система обучается (это теория распознавания образов), во втором случае  p1 = 80, p2 = 99 - матрица 20х100, по которой мы смотрим как распознается наш обьект (в нашем случае картинка)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я понял логику, в distance последовательно должны попасть расчитанные элементы. Есть два варианта решения:

1. Изменить distance[p2 - p1 - i] на distance[i-p1]
2. Используйте List.add()

Comment: Я вызываю distance и передаю ему соответствующие параметры p1 и p2. Для первого случая оно долно обработать матрицу 80х100, во втором 20х100.

Comment: Спасибо)) Все так просто))

Comment: Судя по коду, эти парметры служат для полчения подматрицы. Т.е. для случая с p1=42 и p2 = 50 вы пройдете по элементам matrix[42...49][0..99]. результаты вычисления вы складываете последовательно в distance. Правда зачем-то в обратном порядке.

Comment: Еще можно после объявления distance, добавить счетчик `int index = 0;` А в строке: `distance[p2 - p1 - i] = Math.round(Math.sqrt(rezult));` [p2 - p1 - i] заменить на index++